# Async action creator not dispatching action as expected

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, redux-mock-store

guys.

I have the following async action creator that dispatches another action creator or returns `null` depending on the current state. The problem is that it is invariably returning `null` no matter what the current state is.

```
// actions.js

export const loadPosts = category => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const currentState = getState()
  const posts = currentState.postsByCategory
  const categoryPosts = posts[category]
  const items = categoryPosts.items

  if(items === []) {
    return dispatch(fetchPosts(category))
  }

  return null
}
```

As you can see, the action creator dispatching `fetchPosts()` depends on the value of `items`being equal to an empty array. I am testing it providing it an intial state with the following structure:

```
// initialState
const initialState = {
  postsByCategory: {
    hot: {
      isFetching: false,
      items: []
    }
  }
}
```

I am obviously not accessing the `items` property appropriately, but I cannot see where the error in my code is.
I am testing this with redux-mock-store, creating an instance of a mockStore, and providing it with `initialState`.
Hope you guys can pinpoint the error in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `comparison`

```
if(items === [])
```

In the above code, items will not be `===` to `[]` as they both are of different instances. If you want to check if `items` is empty, please use `items.length === 0`. Hope that helps.

Comment: hey man, it worked. Thanks! I just don't quite get the difference between === [] and using .length === 0. Does it have anything to do with array metadata? Do you have any suggestion of further reading to get a better grasp of this?